# Array index out of bounds exception in matrix multiplication code

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, indexoutofboundsexception

It keeps throwing the exception array index out of bounds for the multiply method, but dimensions are correct. The error appears at this line:

```
mm[r][c]+=multiplier[i][j]*multiplicand[j][i];
```

and at this line:

```
k.multiply_matrix(temp1,temp2,i1,h,i2);
```

I want to know why the exception is thrown and possible modification for my code to run correctly.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class matrixmultiplication
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        matrixmultiplication k=new matrixmultiplication();
        System.out.println("enter how many rows and how many columns");
        Scanner c=new Scanner(System.in);
        String f=c.next();
        String[] x=f.split(",");

        int i1=Integer.parseInt(x[0]);
        int i2=Integer.parseInt(x[1]);
        int[][] temp1=k.enter_thematrix(i1,i2);
        System.out.println("how many columns in the second matrix");
        int h=c.nextInt();
        int[][] temp2=k.enter_thematrix(i2,h);
        k.multiply_matrix(temp1,temp2,i1,h,i2);
    }

    public int[][] enter_thematrix(int d1,int d2)
    {
        Scanner c1=new Scanner(System.in);
        int the_matrix[][]=new int[d1][d2];

        for (int col=0;col<d2;col++)
        {
            for(int row=0;row<d1;row++)
            {
                the_matrix[row][col]=c1.nextInt();
            }
        }
        return the_matrix;
    }

    public void print_matrix(int [][]mm,int a,int s)
    {
        for (int col=0;col<s;col++)
        {
            for(int row=0;row<a;row++)
            {
                System.out.print(mm[a][s]+"\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public void multiply_matrix(int [][]multiplier,int [][]multiplicand,int r,int c,int innerd)
    {
        int [][]mm=new int[r][c];

        for(int c1=0;c1<c;c1++)
        {
            for(int r1=0;r1<r;r1++)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<innerd;i++)
                {
                    for(int j=0;j<innerd;j++)
                    {
                        mm[r][c]+=multiplier[i][j]*multiplicand[j][i];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        print_matrix(mm,r,c);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `i`, `j`, `r`, `c` when the error occurs?

Comment: Also please provide a [mcve]. What have you given as input?

Comment: You should describe the input. As an educated guess I think the problem is that you are inverting the row and column dimensions.

Comment: *"but dimensions are correct"* - Then what *isn't* correct?  Don't just assume, *debug*.  When the exception is thrown, what are the values of the variables you're using to access the arrays?  What are the dimensions of those arrays?  Do you see the difference?  Where in your logic are you trying to access an element outside the bounds of an array and why?

Comment: textbook matrix multiplication is usually a three lop affair, what is the purpose of `innerd`?

Comment: the purpose of the innerd is inner dimension for two matrices to be multiplied they must have compatible for multiplication so the number of columns of the multiplier must equal the number of rows of the multiplicand,so if I input for the first matrix the values 2,2 this gives the columns and the rows for the multiplier then I enter 1 2 3 4 and then I input 2 as the columns for the multiplicand then I enter 1 2 3 4 as the values fir the multiplicand then I run the program and the exception is thrown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you pass `i1` and `i2` to the method, `multiply_matrix`. However `i1` and `i2` are the amount of rows and columns. Arrays start at zero. So if you have a 2d array with two rows and two columns it will have a max index of 1. (0 and 1 are the two positions in the array) So when you call the line:

```
mm[r][c]+=multiplier[i][j]*multiplicand[j][i];
```

You will always have an indexoutofboundsexception because (in this example of a 2 by 2 array) you will be calling the index (2,2) which does not exist. You need to pass that arguments `i1-1` and `i2-1` to the method.

Also a side note I would not have the user enter the rows and columns on the same line and then split it. This is error prone. If a user enters a number, comma, space, and then another number, this will cause an error. Or if the user doesn't type a comma this will also cause an error. It would be better to call `nextInt` on two separate lines. Like this:

```
System.out.println("enter how many rows: ");
Scanner c=new Scanner(System.in);
int i1 = c.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter how many columns: ");
int i2 = c.nextInt();
```